# MySQL time stamp issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a time-stamp, which is returned from PayPal as

```
2010-12-29T20:42:49.929-08:00
```

Now I need to convert it to MySQL DateTime format, using PHP

Anyone is having solution, how to convert it?

Thanks.

Comment: I was going to add an answer based on the DateTime object... but while coding up the example I break down in tears over how messy both PHP as a language, and it's built-in classes can sometimes be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2010-12-29T20:42:49.929-08:00'));
```